# Match address and skip numbers with a particular pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to match this address but it seems to be quite the adventure. This is the correct solution at the moment `\d{1,9},\d{1,2}([\s\w\.]+?)Please find`.

The problem is that I want to include commas in my regex pattern because sometimes the address will have a comma in. When I do this `\d{1,9},\d{1,2}([\s\w\.\,]+?)Please find` it matches all the numbers above the address which I don't want to include.

How can I avoid this? (I am thinking that we can exclude numbers with a particular pattern as the address would ever contain 12.97 or 15.97 etc..).

This is what I want to search for:

```
Ralf
Boson
Chesterford Avenue. 115
81777 Antananarivo
Madagascar
```

Thanks

```
Example Janel tan 40

1,00

25,97

25,97

Example Halfs black 123

1,00

12,97

12,97

Example Halfs black 456

1,00

24,47

24,47

Ralf
Boson
Chesterford Avenue, 115
81777 Antananarivo
Madagascar

Please find
enclosed your invoice in a pdf document.

For more information please read our frequently asked questions (FAQ) here https://example.com/hc/en-us.com
```

Comment: What string do you want to find in the above text? Can you please show us the accepted string?

Comment: Sorry I had to edit the address.

Comment: Try `(?m)^\d{1,9},\d{1,2}\s*\n((?:(?!\d+,\d+$).*\n)*)Please find` or `(?sm)^\d{1,9},\d{1,2}\s*((?:(?!^\d+,\d+$).)*?)Please find`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This pattern `^\d{1,9},\d{1,2}\s*\n((?:(?!\d+,\d+$).*\n)*)Please find` is better than my suggestion excluding matching the leading newlines with `\s*\n` You should post it :)

Comment: Yes this is true, really happy to mark the answer as correct if you make it by tomorrow morning. Otherwise, I'll accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to get the data is to use a negative lookahead (if supported) to match the digit format at the start and repeat matching all the lines that do not start with either that same digit format or `Please find`

Then you can either match the whole line using `.*` (which will also match an empty line) or use a character class to specify what you would allow to match.

```
^\d{1,9},\d{1,2}((?:\r?\n(?!Please find|\d{1,9},\d{1,2}).*)+)\r?\nPlease find
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKOwt6/1)